# Partition Function for Homogenous Potential

Tags: statistical-mechanics

A classical Fluid at temperature T consists of N particles with potential energy
given by a homogeneous function of degree $\alpha$,
\begin{equation}
U(br_{1}, br_{2}, . . . , br_{N} ) =b^{\alpha} U(r_{1}, r_{2}, . . . , r_{N} ) \\
\alpha U(r_{1}, r_{2}, . . . , r_{N} ) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} r_{i} \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial r_{i}}
\end{equation}

I am interested in calculating the Partition function $Z$ as a function of $\dfrac{VT^{-3/{\alpha}}}{N}$ for this system.
Now after doing the momentum integral, we get
\begin{equation}
Z= \dfrac{1}{N!\lambda^{3N}} \int\Pi_{i=1}^{N}~d^3r_{i} e^{-\beta~U(r_{1},...r_{N})}
\end{equation}
Now I can use a change of variable as follows: \begin{equation}
r_{i}= r'_{i} \Bigg(\dfrac{V}{N}\bigg)^{1/3}
\end{equation}
Using this change of variable and the homogenous property I finally got:
\begin{equation}
Z= \dfrac{1}{N!\lambda^{3N}} \Bigg(\dfrac{V}{N}\Bigg)^N\int\Pi_{i=1}^{N}~d^3r'_{i} e^{-\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\Bigg(\dfrac{VT^{-3/{\alpha}}}{N}\Bigg)^{\alpha/3}~~r'_{i}\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial r'_{i}}}
\end{equation}

Now if the particles are indistinguishable, for the given potential $U(r_{1},r_{2},...,r_{N})$, can I write this?(i.e the derivative of the potential is same)
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial r'_{1}}=\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial r'_{2}}
\end{equation}

Comment: I think you can. if particles are indistinguishable , U(r1,r2) will be same as U(r2,r1) as exchanging particles will not lead to change in potential energy. And thus the derivatives are also equal.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Thanks for the comment.